# Proof that function is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I want to prove, that function is Lipschitz continuous. I'm stuck on one step.
I have the solution, but I want to solve it $\textbf{without}$ derivative, so just using definiton. So let

$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R,\ f(x):=\sqrt{x-\sin(x)}$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ So let $x,y \in [0,1].$ Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=...$.

Then $\forall \ x,y \in [0,1]$ with $\lvert x-y \rvert<\delta$,

we have

$\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert=\lvert \sqrt{x-\sin(x)}-\sqrt{y-\sin(y)}\rvert=\Bigg \lvert \frac{x-\sin(x)-y+\sin(y)}{\sqrt{x-\sin(x)}+\sqrt{y-\sin(y)}} \Bigg \rvert=\Bigg \lvert \frac{x-y+\sin(y)-\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x-\sin(x)}+\sqrt{y-\sin(y)}} \Bigg \rvert=$

and now I'm stuck. What have I to do? How can I evaluate this in order to find a Lipschitz constant K?

Comment: How are you defining $\sin x$? The Taylor series?

Comment: @BrianTung yes )

Comment: I suggest proving it **with** the derivative first. Then examine closely why that proof works. Figure out how to use estimates of the derivative to show it without actually taking the derivative. Simplify that proof until you can see what was necessary all along. This isn't cheating. It is how you build up intuition.

Comment: Use maybe $\sin(x)>\frac{2}{\pi}x$ for all $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is straightforward from the concavity of $\sin$ in $[0,\pi/2]$. That should work at least away from $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for help. I did it. It works, because if we look at derivative ( at this limit ) it's bounded.  But I don't understand, how can I evalute it, without this limit)

Comment: @Christoph thank you for tipp, but it didn't help or I used it bad. So I have
$\frac{|x-y+sin(y)-sin(x)|}{|\sqrt{x-sin(x)}|} \leq \frac{|x-y+sin(y)-sin(x)|}{\sqrt{x-\frac{2x}{\pi}}}= \frac{|x-y+sin(y)-sin(x)|}{\sqrt{\frac{(pi-2) \cdot x}{\pi}}}$